# How to update my cordova/phonegap mobile application remotely in android?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have written the mobile app in cordova + angularjs + sqlite. I need to distribute it directly from my server to devices not through the google play.

Now I need to update javascript files stored in `www` directory on android device. I tried file transfer from app directory (`/data/data/my.application.directory/`) to some public device directory or server and vice versa - no problem. But problem is the `www` directory is part of `file:///android_asset/` that is read only so I am not able to store any data in there.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You provide little information about your application, your code and what you are trying to do, but let me try to help you either way.

If what you want to do is modifying files in the www directory in android clients already shipped/downloaded, forget about it, you would need direct access to the device, and this code is bundled when you ship it.

If you are looking for a hot code push solution, [there might be a way of doing so installing additional cordova plugins](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push)

When you publish your application on the store - you pack in it all your web content: html files, JavaScript code, images and so on. There are two ways how you can update it:

- Publish new version of the app on the store. But it takes time,
  especially with the App Store.
- Sacrifice the offline feature and load all the pages online. But as
  soon as Internet connection goes down - application won't work.

Solution: [install cordova-hot-code-push](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push)

Comment: I tried the plugin `cordova-hot-code-push` you mentioned and it works perfectly but it's still just replacing of whole package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'm using for updating my app and I'm not using Google Play or other stores:

I'm using this cordova plugin : https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version to check my actual app version

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(function (version) 
{
    if(version)
        // Check the server reference version
});
```

After, I'm sending the app version number to the server
The server checks the difference between the version sent and the reference version

If the device app version is older, I'm returning the new version to my app client

Comment: I think it's not necessary to use plugin for checking version. Question was about replacing the asset files in app.